# Searching is not working properly in array of objects, all the code is written in stackblitz link

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If i search **TC_E_09_CSMS** it gives all the records of this object.

Below is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hso2p9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have updated the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m8tnkx?file=src/app/app.component.ts). In console you can see the array contains info related to `TC_E_09_CSMS` . Since you didn't provide the expected output, you will see an array of empty objects as well.

Comment: i need to show only the TC_E_09_CSMS on screen after searching. your provided link is not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some problem in your code

The first is how you use keyup, `(keyup)="applyFilter($event);"` event is the event of keyup, $event is not the value of the input, so you should write some like

```
<input #inputID (keyup)="applyFilter(inputID.value);"..>
```

See that use a template reference variable "inputID" to pass the value

The second is that you always iterate over `filteredArray` and filteredArray **not** change

Well, You can use an auxiliar variable finalArray and iterate over this

Your `applyFilter` function can be more compact. Some like

```
  //declare a new variable:
  finalArray=this.filteredArray;

  //your function applyFilter more "compact"
  applyFilter(word) {
    if (!word)
      this.finalArray=this.filteredArray;
    else
    {
    word=word.toLowerCase();
    this.finalArray=this.filteredArray.map((x:any)=>{
         const data=x.header.toLowerCase().indexOf(word)>=0?x.data:
                    x.data.filter((d:any)=>d.testcaseId.toLowerCase()==word)

         return {...x,data:data}
    }).filter(x=>x.data.length>0)
    }
```

BTW, using keyup is one way to filter, but I would prefer use a FormControl(*) and subscribe to valueChange. This allow us use a debounceTime in the way if you change the input quickly don't make severals calls to the input. So

```
//in .html
<input [formControl]="search"...>

//your code
search:FormControl=new FormControl()
ngOnInit(){
   this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(200)
   )
   .subscribe(res=>{
       this.applyFilter(res)
   })
}
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-di5znp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with all the changes

(*)don't forget import ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module